# How to get the exception source in target layout when logging exceptions with NLog?

Tags: nlog

Suppose when we log StackTrace we write
`<column name="EXCEPTION STACKTRACE" layout="${exception:format=StackTrace}" />`

In same way,  how can I write `Exception.source` value in target layout?

Comment: Created https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/3558 for you

Comment: NLog 4.6.7 has been released with support for `format=Source`. See also https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (NLog 4.6.6) you need to extend the current ExceptionLayoutRenderer, e.g.

```cs
[LayoutRenderer("exception-custom")]
[ThreadAgnostic]
public class CustomExceptionLayoutRenderer : ExceptionLayoutRenderer
{
    public bool RenderSource { get; set; } = true;

    protected override void AppendMessage(System.Text.StringBuilder sb, Exception ex)
    {
        base.AppendMessage(sb, ex);
        if (RenderSource && ex.Source != null)
        {
            sb.Append("Source:");
            sb.Append(ex.Source);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
// register 
NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer.Register<CustomExceptionLayoutRenderer>("exception-custom");
NLog.LogManager.Configuration = NLog.LogManager.Configuration.Reload(); // reload
```

In your nlog.config:`${exception-custom}`, `${exception-custom:RenderSource=false}` etc.

In NLog 4.6.7 we will add  `${exception:format=Source}` (Thanks Rolf!)

Comment: Thanks Julian! It is working and I will be excited about the new version.

Comment: NLog 4.6.7-   still I am not getting source value.  " <column name="EXCEPTION SOURCE" layout="${exception:format=Source}"/>"

Comment: Hi Julian, LayoutRenderer is also stopped working for source. (above answer code)

Comment: Check the internal log. Sounds like ano an other issue

Comment: Just a small cautionary tale - make sure you are calling _logger.LogError(Exception, String)! I got the arguments mixed up which matched (String, params object?[]) and didn't spot it...